# Does Bitcoin no longer fulfill its original purpose?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transaction-fees

The [Bitcoin whitepaper](https://bitcoin.org/bitcoin.pdf) details "a purely peer-to-peer version of electronic cash", usable for "small casual transactions".

According to [BitInfoCharts](https://bitinfocharts.com/comparison/bitcoin-transactionfees.html#3m), the average Bitcoin transaction fee is currently 58 USD.

Is Bitcoin no longer usable for its original purpose of being a peer-to-peer version of electronic cash?

Comment: The bitcoin lightning network is arguably more 'peer-to-peer' than the base layer, and it is perfect for extremely small transactions.

Answer (score 1):

> Does Bitcoin no longer fulfill its original purpose?

It does. Original purpose included decentralization and censorship resistance which still exists. I did not start researching about Bitcoin because I found a new way to transact online which is quicker and cheaper than my bank transactions, I started using Bitcoin for different reasons. So I assume things can be different for everyone and one whitepaper cannot include them all. Whitepaper is not a Bible and Bitcoin is not a religion. Bitcoin is a software (protocol for decentralized network in which you don't trust anyone) that is evolving every day.

> The Bitcoin whitepaper details "a purely peer-to-peer version of electronic cash", usable for "small casual transactions".

It's still peer to peer if you run full node, it's still electronic. Small casual transactions work better using layer 2 and it's not difficult to understand that things can scale in **layers**.

There are layers in almost everything we use in computers and this approach is not limited to Bitcoin scaling.

If everything has to be done on-chain and every full node needs to sync it, do you think everyone will be able to run a full node? Did the whitepaper mention that full nodes do not matter and they can be run by few companies in some data centers?

What will you achieve by spending $10 on a coffee with low fees if you can't run your own full node and trust someone else?

> Is Bitcoin no longer usable for its original purpose of being a peer-to-peer version of electronic cash?

It is usable and people who have been following Bitcoin development are using layer 2 solutions like Lightning Network.

Recent example: Okex supporting LN for bitcoin deposit/withdrawal